# Highcharts more and highcharts guage issue

Tags: highcharts

My high charts more is giving the following erro:

> highcharts-more.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: I is not a function

I am calling the highcharts-more on the page with the folllowing:
https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js

I see that the highcharts-more file has been updated today. If I use the older version which is:
https://code.highcharts.com/4.2.2/highcharts-more.js

Then I start getting error in the solid-guage.js which is as follows:

> solid-gauge.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function

Plus the gayge fill color is not functioning properly as well.

Comment: Hi, Your problem may be connected with catched files from previous Highcharts version. 

You can check if your chart works in incognito mode and delete your cookies.

Comment: Thanx Grzegorz Blachliński, its working now as my local highcharts was old version and updating it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating my local file highcharts.js to latest version solved the issue as, highcharts-more and solid-guage being called from website were updated to new versions along with highcharts.js.